# Calling DataGridViewEventArgs e from another form

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, passwords

I'm kind of stuck in a trivial spot, I want to execute a method when password is correct but I'm unable to call a method from another form, this is my code in Form1:

```
public void grid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            if (chkbox1.Checked == true)
            {
                Form3 pw = new Form3();
                pw.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string imgPath = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = imgPath;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                    pProcess.Start();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Does not contain a File.", "No Files added.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in Form3:

```
public void insertbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM password WHERE pass ILIKE '%" + password.Text + "%'", CRUD.con);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.grid_CellDoubleClick(); <---
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password, try again.","Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Let me explain what I am really trying to do here, in Form1 I have multiple text fields, a checkbox option (to make the entry private) and an option to upload a file with the entry (PDF document). On an entry where the is no checkbox checked (field in DB with boolean value) the user is able to open that row/entry with a simple double click and view the PDF file, but on an entry where the boolean value is true (checkbox checked on entry) user is prompted to enter a password to access the private PDF document (Form3 is the form for password validation). So, to put it simple, wrong password = unable to view file, right password = close Form 3 and open the file. This is my code so far with your help:

Form 1:

```
 public void grid_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            if (Private.Checked == true)
            {
                Form3 Form3 = new Form3();
                
                if (Form3.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string imgPath = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = imgPath;
                        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                        pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                        pProcess.Start();
                        
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("File not uploaded with the entry", "No PDF File uploaded.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string imgPath = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                    pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = imgPath;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                    pProcess.Start();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File not uploaded with the entry", "No PDF File uploaded.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Form3:

```
public void okbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM password WHERE pass = '" + password.Text + "'", CRUD.con);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
       
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Access granted.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password, try again.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        
    }
```

I am well aware that the code should be safer and better constructed than this.
I'm just testing and trying it out.

To make it more clear, Form3 is only used for validating the password. Form1 is where the 'magic' happens (not yet clearly).

Comment: Put the code of  `grid_CellDoubleClick` event handler into a new public method and call it from the event handler and the other form.

Comment: Tried to make PasswordMethod() with the same code but i have to add the "object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e" as the argument to access datagridview row indexes, no? Then i get the same error when calling PasswordMethod()

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I commented out that line and forgot to show it here. What I am trying to do exactly is to open Form3 when the user double clicks on a row which contains true value on checkbox, which will then prompt a user to insert password to Form3 to view the rows document. If the password is correct i want to run the grid_CellDoubleClick code like it normaly runs on a row with false value on checkbox.

Comment: You should show Form3 with `ShowDialog(this)` which will set the parent to Form1. Set the `DialogResult` to `Ok` if the PW is correct, otherwise to `Cancel`. Change the `if` `else` part of your event so that the process start code is executed depending on the DialogResult.

Comment: I'm sorry if I took your comments wrongly, thank you again for trying. I'm considering Alex B's advice to validate password with showDialog() but I'm not sure how to replace my if/else code with it. I feel the logic there but i just cant write it without errors, maybe i need a coffee.

Comment: Look at this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexB. Believe it or not, I just made it work with that exact example, found it myself as well. Works just fine but it doesn't load event when it closes the dialog, closer than before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you update your question so I can see your actual code?

Comment: @AlexB. Just did that

Comment: You have to set DialotgResult in Form3.okbutton_Click

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly where, could you explain it in more details please?

Comment: `if (dt.Rows.Count == 1) DialogResult = DialogResult.OK else DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel this.Close()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex.B, i appreciate your effort, you made my life a lot easier :)

Comment: Do you have a working solution now?

Comment: Yes sir, I do. Fixed the spaghetti code and added a few more things. Once again, thank you for your time